# Nodejs mysql request doesn't update timestamp

Tags: mysql, node.js, unix-timestamp

MySQL request for updating timestamps not want to update why ? what is wrong?
I try two methods

Method 1

```
mysqlConnection.query('UPDATE `games` SET `starttime`= current_timestamp() WHERE `id` = \'' + current_game + '\'', function(err, row, fields) {});
```

Method 2

```
mysqlConnection.query('UPDATE `games` SET `starttime`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE `id` = \'' + current_game + '\'', function(err, row, fields) {});
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: mm i not getting error script worked without error , but i checked my table in mysql and curently stamp not updated .